# 3DCityDB Export not working

Tags: kml, citygml

I'm working with some CityGML models within 3DCityDB. 
For visualization purposes I now want to export some of my buildings to KML with the exporter tool.
When I draw the bounding box over my area of interest I get some coordinates, but after exporting it says

> number of processed geometries: 0

When I try to export only one building using its gml_id I get a kml file, but when I open it in Google Earth Pro I end up somewhere in the middle of the Arctic Ocean without seeing my building. I assume there's a problem with the SRID.
Anyone else encountered this problem or has a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that the SRID in the database conforms to what you know your geometry that you imported is? You can check in database_srs table of your citydb schema.

Comment: i just did and there may be the cause of the problem. In the table database_srs the SRID is 25833, whereas in my data it's 5650. But I'm struggling to find the OGC GML conformant CRS identifier, which needs to specified in the create_db.bat process when setting up the citydb-schema

Comment: I do now remember deliberating about that create_db script too. If you're running it interactively I think it suggests a German focused CRS and it might default to that if you don't enter anything. In my database_srs I have SRID set as "27700" and the gml_srs_name as: "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700" which corresponds to my data. I must've set this myself so maybe try fresh install of 3D CityDB / run through of the scripts.